# Ubuntu Login Loop since installing AMD Driver

Tags: boot, login

I have a Ubuntu Login Loop issue.

I have tried hitting <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> for GRUB menu during boot and I've tried <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>ALT</kbd> <kbd>F2</kbd> and no joy.  I have been able to boot the system using a USB stick and the drive is there all in one piece etc, but I have NO idea how to fix the issue from terminal given that I booted using the stick.

The issue seems to stem from an AMD Driver that I installed earlier today.  As soon as I restarted my system after install the Loop was created.

Comment: to be clear, I want to switch from the USB drive to the permanent SSD drive so as to remove the AMD drive causing the problem.